# Hibernate Using Merge on concurrent Update or Delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there a way for me to know if an detached entity is in the session cache. I have the following scenario.

```
public void method (Entity entityObject)
{
       //List Associated objects and do some process     
       Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GroupMembers.class);
       criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("group", group));
       criteria.createCriteria("group", "group", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
       List<GroupMembers> members = (List<GroupMembers>) criteria.list();

          ...

        entityObject= (Entity) session.merge(entityObject);

        if (SomeCondition){
        session.delete(entityObject);
        }

}
```

This works fine most of the time except in the following scenario. Where the entityObject is deleted by another transaction. What I want is for session.delete(entityObject) to fail because the entityObject is already deleted. However, because of session.merge(entityObject) a record is inserted to the database if the entity can not be found in the cache or DB so delete always succeeds.

---

Updated.
This works but I am doing an extra select at the beginning... Is this a good way?

```
public void method (Entity entityObject)
{
      Entity entityObjectCopy = session.get(Entity.class, entityObject.getId())

       if(entityObjectCopy == null)
       {
       //List Associated objects and do some process     
       Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GroupMembers.class);
       criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("group", group));
       criteria.createCriteria("group", "group", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
       List<GroupMembers> members = (List<GroupMembers>) criteria.list();

          ...

        entityObject= (Entity) session.merge(entityObject);
        }    

        if (SomeCondition){
        session.delete(entityObject);
        }
}
```

Comment: How using `refresh(Object object)` method instead of `merge()`?

Comment: @Suninsky I tried refresh but I get the exception org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Comment: @Suninsky please note that, that is why I used merged in the first place. As the loading of associated objects loads the group entity with the same identifier.